# Save user search history and result

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have an WPF application with about 20 different search dialogs. I want to save users search history and latest search results for all the different search dialogs but I am not allowed to store it in our database.

Right now I have a UserSettingsCollection class that contains all this information, I serialize it to JSON string and store it in a variable in Settings.settings. I am going to move it to a userSettings.json file instead since currently, it serializes from class to JSON to XML.

I have to keep serialize and deserialize the string to load and save the settings when the dialogs open/closes. Is there a more efficient way to do it? Or maybe a more "standard" way so the next programmer looking at it doesn't think a monkey wrote the code.

Comment: Why don't you want in the Database? And no, there isn't a practical way of appending data to a JSON Array of Objects without deserializing it and rewriting the entire file

Comment: @MindSwipe Sorry my bad, it should say that I am not allowed to.

Comment: @MindSwipe Do you have any suggestions where I could save the file?

Comment: Does your application have its own folder where it has config files and such? If so then maybe there or in the `%appdata%\YourApplicationName`. Also I highly recommend that you limit the JSON file/ list to something along the lines of 100 entries as not to read/ write an ever increasingly large file

Comment: @MindSwipe Thank you I found this path to save it in `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.
I have tried to figure out how much I can store in my JSON file so thank you for your recommendation.
I'm only saving the latest 5 searches for each dialog. But I had hoped I also could save the search results, which I guess I have to scratch now.